# JPA/Hibernate comparing floats fails with decimal point

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Am using JPA/Hibernate to query a table. I need to retrieve all rows that has a value of '2.1' in a float column.

Java model

```
@Column(name = "MANAGEMENT_API_VERSION")
private Float managementAPIVersion;
```

sql

```
create table supported_api_versions (
    device_id int8 not null,
    management_api_version float4
);
```

I am using JPA/Hibernate CriteriaBuilder to add a condition for the query while joining with another table

```
Expression<Float> managementAPIVersion = deviceSupportApiVersionJoin.<Float>get("managementAPIVersion");

Expression<Float> mgmtApiVer = cb.literal(Float.valueOf(mgmtApiVersion));
conditions.add(cb.equal(managementAPIVersion, mgmtApiVer));
```

This works fine when the mgmtApiVersion has a value like 2 but does not work when the value has a decimal point like 2.1 
The root cause seems to be that the generated sql does not have a quote around the floating decimal point value

```
from devices device0_ inner join supported_api_versions supporteda1_ on device0_.id=supporteda1_.device_id where supporteda1_.management_api_version=2.1
```

A query on sql with quotes around 2.1 returns a match while the one without the quotes does not return any match.

What must I change in the CriteriaBuilder query or in the mapping to force Hibernate to query a float the right way.

Comment: no reason why a floating point number should have quotes around it (i.e to do a direct conversion from String to float representation) ... that is not "the right way". If you want string comparison then put the float field as a String in your class. Alternatively you do a query where the floating point value is between 2 values.

Comment: I am not looking for string comparison. All I want to do is to ensure the value is 2.1f   SQL just does not work for floating point without quotes with = or >= comparison. It does work if I add the quotes.